# How can I develop an app that integrates with box using oauth and that can be installed on multiple URLs?

Tags: oauth, box-api

I would like to create an App that allows companies to easily integrate their systems (specifically, ServiceNow instances) with Box. But if I register an App with Box, I can only provide one redirect URL. So I do not see a way to deploy my App on different instances (servers) that use different URLs (that are not known in advance).
Is this not a use case that OAuth is designed for? Or am I simply missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The box implementation of OAuth is relativity kind in this respect - you can leave the redirect URL blank when you create the app, and pass it though in your initial OAuth call.
The URL syntax will be

```
?oauthpopupcallback=< wherever >
```

Trying to get UI integration ( Web App integration) to work with multiple servers is another matter - for that you need a redirection service.